# Find if the mouse position changed during mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, web

I have a text that when I long press the mouse button (700 ms), I will activate an text editor over that text. During this time (when the mouse is pressed) I have to check if the mouse position has moved. The problem is, that I only have one event, mouse down pressed event.

How do I found out if the mouse has been moved?
I have tried to take a new event but I am a beginner to jquery so I couldn't achieve what I wanted to.

this is the function where i get the event.

```
  onTaskItemMouseDown: function (event) {

        // We only check the left click
        if (event.button !== 0) { return true; }

        var that = this,
            initialX = event.pageX,
            initialY = event.pageY;

        // Set timeout
        console.log("x=" + initialX);
        console.log("y=" + initialY);
        this.pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {


            clearTimeout(that.pressTimer);
            that.pressTimer = 0;
            that.onEditTask(event, that.$(event.currentTarget).closest(".task").find(".dropdown-container").data("task-id"));
        }, MindomoUtils.longClickDuration);

        return true;
    },
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Comment: I read, but I didn't understood. could you help me a little? I told you I am a beginner at this

Comment: Start by reproducing the examples on that page, and tinker with them to see what happens.

Comment: yes, I understand and I usually to this. but now I am at work, and they switched me to web development, which is now my field and I don't have that much time. thank you anyway!

Comment: @CristiHoldunu The basic principle is that you clear the timeout (using the `clearTimeout()` function) on `mousemove`. In order to do that, however, it will need to be in scope for the `mousemove` event handler function.

Comment: I solved it by creating en mouseMoveHandler and then i used bind and unbind to tie the handler with the div on which I had my mouse pressed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for mousemove event.

I can see you already using jQuery so here is an example for you.

HTML for output

```
<ul class="output"></ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('mousedown', onMouseDown)
$(document).on('mousemove', onMouseMove)
$(document).on('mouseup', onMouseUp)

var mouseIsDown = false

function onMouseDown(event) {
    // set boolean true
    mouseIsDown = true
    $('.output').append($('<li>').text('Mouse down - x: ' + event.pageX + ' y: ' + event.pageY))
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    if(mouseIsDown) {
        $('.output').append($('<li>').text('Mouse moving - x: ' + event.pageX + ' y: ' + event.pageY))
    }
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    // set boolean false again
    mouseIsDown = false
    $('.output').append($('<li>').text('Mouse up - x: ' + event.pageX + ' y: ' + event.pageY))
}
```

[Here you can play with it yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/CJHfd/)